# Function template fallback overload

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to produce compile type error with custom message for function template if there is no viable overload found.

This code works but i would like to remove redundant (from my point) `enable_if_t<not is_integral_v<T>,` in last overload.

```
using namespace std;
using byte_vector = vector<uint8_t>

template<typename T>
enable_if_t<is_integral_v<T>,
byte_vector&> operator<<(byte_vector&bv, T const& v){
//ToDo C++20 if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::big)
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
    std::reverse_iterator<uint8_t *> first{(uint8_t *) (&v + 1)}, last{(uint8_t *) (&v)};
#else
    uint8_t * first = (uint8_t*)&ui, last = (uint8_t*)(&ui+1)};
#endif
    bv.insert(end(bv), first, last);    
    return bv;
}
template<>
byte_vector& operator<<(byte_vector&bv, uint8_t const& v){
    bv.push_back(v);
    return bv;
}
/// Produce compile type error for non-integral types => easier to find what's wrong
template<typename T>
enable_if_t<not is_integral_v<T>,
byte_vector&> operator<<(byte_vector&bv, T const& v){
    static_assert(is_integral_v<T>,"operator<<(byte_vector&,T) implemented for integral types only");
}
```

I plan to move to C++20 but current standard is C++17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the static assert to the primary template like

```
template<typename T>
byte_vector& operator<<(byte_vector&bv, T const& v){
    // assert if not integral
    static_assert(is_integral_v<T>,"operator<<(byte_vector&,T) implemented for integral types only");
    // since it is, do the stuff
//ToDo C++20 if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::big)
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
    std::reverse_iterator<uint8_t *> first{(uint8_t *) (&v + 1)}, last{(uint8_t *) (&v)};
#else
    uint8_t * first = (uint8_t*)&ui, last = (uint8_t*)(&ui+1)};
#endif
    bv.insert(end(bv), first, last);    
    return bv;  
}

template<>
byte_vector& operator<<(byte_vector&bv, uint8_t const& v){
    bv.push_back(v);
    return bv;
}
```

Comment: I will have C++20 support latter. Now C++17

Comment: @kyb `if constexpr` is C++17.  It's the  `std::endian::native == std::endian::big` part of your comment that is C++20

Comment: Why `if constexpr`? You could just `static_assert`